# Is [us-constitution] a useful tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there any purpose for the [us-constitution](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-constitution) tag, considering that US-specific questions should also be tagged with [united-states](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states), and [us-constitution](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-constitution) does not provide any information not given by the combination of [united-states](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) and [constitutional-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constitutional-law)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not particularly advocating for it, but is there a corner case for a question which is about the applicability of the US constitution to the law of a particular state? E.g.:

[california](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/california)[us-constitution](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-constitution)

Vs.:

[california](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/california)[constitutional-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constitutional-law)

The former is clear whereas the latter could be about Californian constitutional law. We could add another tag:

[california](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/california)[constitutional-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/constitutional-law)[united-states](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states)

But is that starting to lose focus? It's a bit less clear from the tags whether the constitutional tag attaches to the calfornia tag or the US tag or both.